# Triggering an ajax call from a newly added row using jquery to the existing table

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to view student details in a table. Initially, my table has only one row, where 3 columns University, Department and Names are present. When I select a university from the university drop down, an ajax call is triggered and it populates the corresponding departments available in that university in the department drop down. when I choose the department, a second ajax call is triggered which populates the names drop down  based on the value in the university and department dropdowns.

When I want to search for the next student, I click on the add button, which renders the next row. However, In this newly added row, when I select a university from the dropdown, ajax call is not triggered.

Can you help me achieve this?

Student.html

```
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Add" class="plusbtn1" />
</div>
<table border="0" width="80%" id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td class="lightGrayedTD">University</td>
        <td class="lightGrayedTD">Department</td>
        <td class="lightGrayedTD">Student Names</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="University">
                <option value="IT" >NYU</option>
                <option value="CSC">NYU Poly</option>
                <option value="EEE">Business School</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="year">
                <option value=""> --Select Year-- </option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="names">
                <option value="" label=""> --Select Name-- </option>        
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Add.js

```
$('.plusbtn1').click(function(){
    $('#mytable tr').last().after(
        '<tr>
            <td>
                <select id="University">
                    <option value="IT" >NYU</option>
                    <option value="CSC">NYU Poly</option>
                    <option value="EEE">Business School</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="year">
                    <option value=""> --Select Year-- </option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="names">
                    <option value="" label=""> --Select Name-- </option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>'
    );
});
```

ajax.js

```
//populating Department dropdown
$('#dept').change(function(event) {
    var dept = $('#dept :selected').text();       
    $.get("ajax.html", {
        deptName : dept
    }, function(response) {
        var select = $('#year');
        select.find('option').remove();
        $.each(response, function(index, value) {
            $('<option>').val(value).text(value).appendTo(select);
        });
    });
});

//populating names dropdown
$('#year').change(function(event) {
    var dept = $('#dept :selected').text();
    var year = $('#year :selected').text();      
    $.get("ajax1.html", {
        dept : dept,
        year : year
    }, function(response) {
        var select = $('#names');
        select.find('option').remove();
        $.each(response, function(index, value) {
            $('<option>').val(value).text(value).appendTo(select);
        });
    });
});
```

ajax and ajax1

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajax", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody   
public void ajax(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response) 
throws IOException {
    String uni = request.getParameter("universityName");
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list=cheDao1.retrievedept(uni);
    String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.getWriter().write(json);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/ajax1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void ajax1(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
    response) throws IOException {
    String uni = request.getParameter("universityName");
    String dept = request.getParameter("deptName");
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list=cheDao1.retrievenames(uni,dept );
    String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.getWriter().write(json);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a JSFiddle that includes your code with the bug. We cannot help if we cannot re-create the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a FAQ.

1. ID must be unique so use class.
2. use delegation:

`$("#mytable").on("change",".year",function{ ....  }`
`$("#mytable").on("change",".dept",function{ ....  }`

3. Please note that calling one server process with different parameters would make the code simpler - especially if you pass it the context and name of select but I did not change major logic.

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://plungjan.name/SO/testajaxuni.html)

Assuming the data returned is on the form

`{"1":"dept1","2":"dept2","3":"dept3"}`

```
$(function() { 
  var $clonerow = $("#mytable tr").clone();
  $('.plusbtn1').on("click",function() {
    $('#mytable tr').last().after($clonerow);
  });

  //populating Department dropdown
  $(document).on("change",'.University',function(event) {
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var uni = $(':selected',this).text();
    if (uni.indexOf("--") !=-1) return;
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.html",
        context: $row,
        data: {universityName:uni},
        success: function(response) {
          console.log($(this),response);
          var $select = $(this).find('.dept').empty();
          $('<option>').val("").text(" --Please select dept.--").appendTo($select);
          $.each(response, function(index, value) {
            $('<option>').val(value).text(value).appendTo($select);
          });
          $select.append(response);
        }  
    });
  }); 
  $(document).on("change",'.dept',function(event) {
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var uni = $row.find('.University :selected').text();
    if (uni.indexOf("--") !=-1) return; // please select
    var dept = $(':selected',this).text();
    if (dept.indexOf("--") !=-1) return;
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax1.html",
        context: $row,
        data: {universityName: uni,
               deptName: dept},
        success: function(response) {
          console.log($(this),response);
          var $select = $(this).find('.year').empty();
          $('<option>').val("").text(" --Please select year.--").appendTo($select);
          $.each(response, function(index, value) {
            $('<option>').val(value).text(value).appendTo($select);
          });
         $select.append(response);
        }  
    });
  });

  //populating names dropdown
  $(document).on("change",'.year',function(event) {
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var uni = $row.find('.University :selected').text();
    if (uni.indexOf("--") !=-1) return; // please select
    var dept = $row.find('.dept :selected').text();
    if (dept.indexOf("--") !=-1) return; // please select
    var year = $(':selected',this).text();
    if (year.indexOf("--") !=-1) return; // please select
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax2.html",
        context: $row,
        data:{universityName: uni,
              deptName: dept,
              year: year},
        success: function(response) {
          var $select = $(this).find('.names').empty();
          $('<option>').val("").text(" --Please select name --").appendTo($select);
          $.each(response, function(index, value) {
            $('<option>').val(value).text(value).appendTo($select);
          });
          $select.append(response);
        }  
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Please see update. I changed from ID to CLASS in the html too. I cannot test since I do not have your backend available

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, the ajax call is triggered, but unfortunately the drop down list is not getting populated. There is some error in the response function. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: No console errors and yes the ajax.html returns a list. I actually replaced your response function with mine and the drop down lists were populated, the problem I faced was the departments of all rows were updated according to my last row's university because we are using class. I don't know how to make it row specific. can you please help me with that?

Comment: Can you post a fictive but syntactically correct example of your ajax.html?

Comment: It is possible that the code should be `var $select = $row.find('.year'); $select.empty();`

Comment: If I use your response function, it is not even going inside ajax.html, So I suppose something is wrong in that function because when I replace it with mine, it's going to ajax.html and populating the drop down list. Can you please check if something is wrong in the response function?

Comment: I have changed the ajax to pass the context of the row to the success handler

Comment: Can you post an example of ajax.html and ajax1,html?

Comment: I updated the $.get to a $.ajax. I wrongly tried to add a context to a $.get

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. But even this doesnot populate the drop down. I've posted my ajax and ajax1. Can you please take a look of that and help me?

Comment: I need the output from your code, not the code itself

Comment: You mean output from my ajax and ajax1? Both retrieve a list from the database which is used to populate the drop down lists.

Comment: I see one issue. We need to use `data:{universityName:uni}`, instead of `university:uni,` - see update

Comment: I spent FAR to long on fixing this :/ - my code now demonstratively works assuming data returned is on the form `{"1":"dept1","2":"dept2","3":"dept3"}` and that each select has the appropriate class